# SegFault after taking input from user with fgets()

Tags: c

So I'm writing a program where i want to get the Customer's info but after I enter the name there's a Segmetation fault (core dumbed) and i don't understand why, I've run similar code before and it ran just fine. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Customer
{
    char* first_name;
    char* last_name;
    int   age;
    char* password;
};

struct Customer customer;

void get_customer_info()
{
    printf("Enter your first name: ");
    fgets(customer.first_name, 30, stdin);
}

int main(void)
{
    get_customer_info();

    printf("%s\n", customer.first_name);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a typical beginner error. You did not allocate memory for the fields of the `struct`.

Try re-writing the struct as:

```
struct Customer
{
    char first_name[100];
    char last_name[100];
    int   age;
    char password[100];
};
```

Alternatively, you can allocate memory with `malloc()`.